# How to configure RAD Server to send compressed responses?

Tags: delphi, delphi-11-alexandria, rad-server

I'm building a prototype for a new C/S app using RAD Server.

I want to get compressed some large requests to speed up their transmission, so I send them with `Accept-Encoding` to `gzip` on their Header, as explained here for generic REST servers:

https://www.developer-experts.net/en/2018/10/12/better-performance-with-rest-compression/

But my RAD Server still serves those requests in plain text. Do I have to check myself the Accept-Encoding Header on the server side and compress those responses ?

The "The Complete Guide to Embarcadero RAD Server eBook" doesn't have any mentions to gzip, Accept-Encoding, Compression, ... and I haven't been able to find any other documentation about compressing RAD Server requests, so I don't know if the problem is that I have to program that compression myself or I need to configure RAD Server so it reacts to the Accept-Encoding received.

Comment: Just because your client announces to support one specific compression it doesn't mean the server supports/serves it. Since RAD Server is only a REST server and not a full fledged HTTP server I think it doesn't support any [HTTP compression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_compression#Content-Encoding_tokens). Compression alone is not the easiest task either, and combining it with HTTP also needs attention for details.

Comment: In production RAD Server should be setup on a Web Server which will do the compression if desired. For example IIS has dynamic compression to do this for responses from handlers like an ISAPI module (which RAD Server runs as on IIS).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In production RAD Server should be running on a Web Server which can be configured to do the compression if desired. Running RAD Server standalone is really just for convenience while doing development and testing.

Both IIS and Apache have settings to compress dynamic content like what RAD Server generates.